How to trigger fluent validation on change of a dependent property value change?
I have a Boolean property 'AnyLetter' depending on five other Boolean properties. The fluent validation is working when I hit on submit but I would like it trigger like 'Location' property, when value change.
View model
public record AlphabetViewModel
{
    public bool AddDate { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
    public bool E { get; set; }
    public bool AnyLetter => A || B || C || D || E;
}


Fluent Validator
 public class AlphabetViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<AlphabetViewModel>
 {
     public AlphabetViewModelValidator()
     {
         When(x => x.AddDate.HasValue, () =>
         {
             RuleFor(x => x.Location).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Location is a required field.");
             RuleFor(x => x.AnyLetter).NotEqual(false).WithMessage("At least 1 letter must be selected.");
         }
     }
}

UI Code
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <label for="Location">Location*</label>
        <SfTextBox Enabled="true" ID="Location*" Placeholder="Enter" maxlength="100" TabIndex="10"
                   @bind-Value="AlphabetViewModel.Location"/>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> AlphabetViewModel.Location)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <label for="AnyLetter">Any Letter*</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>  AlphabetViewModel. AnyLetter)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label for="A">A</label>
        <SfCheckBox id="A" TChecked="bool" TabIndex="12" @bind-Checked=" AlphabetViewModel.A"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label for="B">B</label>
        <SfCheckBox id="B" TChecked="bool" TabIndex="13" @bind-Checked=" AlphabetViewModel.B"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label for="C">C</label>
        <SfCheckBox id="Collision" TChecked="bool" TabIndex="14" @bind-Checked=" AlphabetViewModel.C"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label for="D">D</label>
        <SfCheckBox id="D" TChecked="bool" TabIndex="15" @bind-Checked=" AlphabetViewModel.D"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label for="E">E</label>
        <SfCheckBox id="E" TChecked="bool" TabIndex="16" @bind-Checked=" AlphabetViewModel.E"/>
    </div>
</div>

When I change the value for Location the error message is disappearing but the same not happening for AnyLetter property, means the errors is not going away when I change any of the check boxes.
I tried to change the rules like below, but still the error message not going away on checkbox change.
When(x => (x.A || x.B || x.C || x.D || x.E) == false, () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.AnyLetter).NotEqual(false).WithMessage("At least 1 letter must be selected.");
});

RuleFor(x => x.AnyLetter).NotEqual(false).DependentRules(() =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.A).NotEqual(false);
    RuleFor(x => x.B).NotEqual(false);
    RuleFor(x => x.C).NotEqual(false);
    RuleFor(x => x.D).NotEqual(false);
    RuleFor(x => x.E).NotEqual(false);

}).WithMessage("At least 1 letter must be selected.");



ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator also tried but it did not work.. Any one has any idea on this?
Thanks in advance.
